# Multiple pages in single popup

Tags: html, css, web, popup

I am new to web development and I am working on a small project but got stuck in this problem, I simply want to create a popup menu that has multiple pages like when the user clicks on the Next button (in the popup menu) after submitting all the details the next menu will be shown and on the next menu there will be 2 buttons prev, next and similarly for other pages and all this thing would be in the single popup menu.

I tried a lot but I don't know how to do this and I also didn't find any useful stuff or a similar query on the internet so it will be very helpful for me if anyone solves my problem.

**Edit**

```
#popup{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: solid 1.5px rgb(34, 34, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


#popup >#popup1 > h1{
    font-family: "Mark Pro", -apple-system, blinkmacsystemfont, "Segoe UI", roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    transform: translate(18%,0);
    width: 600px;
}

#popup >#popup1> #close_butt {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#popup >#popup1> #close_butt > button{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: "Mark Pro", -apple-system, blinkmacsystemfont, "Segoe UI", roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#popup >#popup1> #close_butt  > button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(71, 71, 252);
    color: white;
}

#popup.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 400px;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image1{
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 50px;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image2{
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 50px;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image1:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image2:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image1 > img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image2 > img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: -65px;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image1 > p{
    font-family: "Mark Pro", -apple-system, blinkmacsystemfont, "Segoe UI", roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 450;
}

#popup >#popup1> .inner > .image2 > p{
    transform: translate(0,35px);
    font-family: "Mark Pro", -apple-system, blinkmacsystemfont, "Segoe UI", roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 450;

}

#popup >#popup1> .next{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#popup>#popup1>.next > button{
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 255);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: "Mark Pro", -apple-system, blinkmacsystemfont, "Segoe UI", roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#popup > #popup1.active{
    transform:translateX(-200px);
}

#popup > #popup2{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    transform:translateX(100px);
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you can't insert code, at least try inserting an image.

Comment: @B001ᛦ popup menu means I have a popup in which there are some input fields for user details like name, mobile number and when the user clicks the next button there will be some other input fields and code is simple CSS there is nothing to see there.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Ok I edited .

Comment: @Green I inserted code please help.

Comment: do you have any html?

Comment: @Green Yes, of course.

Comment: @amrit Gupta, can you insert it into the question?

Comment: check out this codepen, author gets around this problem by using multiple modals and referencing them between each other. https://codepen.io/adambui/pen/KmJwdw

Comment: @AMR Thanks, it will be helpful for me.